# How to combine two attributes on select2 in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to attribute kodepos and kabupaten in one dropdown. and kodepos and kabupaten attributes are included in the database. Can anyone help me? thank you

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'origin')->label('Origin')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(MKota::find()->all(),'kodepos','kodepos'),
    'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Kode Pos','required' => true,'style'=>'width:500px','maxlength' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]);
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'origin_name')->label('Origin')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(MKota::find()->all(),'kabupaten','kabupaten'),
    'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Kota Asal','required' => true,'style'=>'width:500px','maxlength' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: not clear what are the names of the `attributes` that you want to show there? there are 2 different select dropdowns that you are talking about, you need to add which attributes you want to show as text for the first and second drop-down.

Comment: sorry, I want to attribute kodepos and kabupaten in one dropdown

Comment: you want a single dropdown instead of 2 drop-downs ? if i am getting you correctly

Comment: i have added an answer below with an update see **EDIT**  part for correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `ArrayHelper::map()` to use the `closure` for the third parameter or the `$to` parameter and return the 2 fields concatenated as you want.

The field names are not clear that you want to show as text in the first and second drop-down so I assume the integer value to be coming from the `id` field.

I will add the code that will show the `id` and `kodepos` concatenated as the text for the first drop-down and show the `id` and `kabupaten` concatenated as the text for the second drop-down. Change them accordingly in the code

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'origin')->label('Origin')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(MKota::find()->all(),'kodepos',function($model){return $model->id.$model->kodepos}),
    'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Kode Pos','required' => true,'style'=>'width:500px','maxlength' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]);
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'origin_name')->label('Origin')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(MKota::find()->all(),'kabupaten',function($model){return $model->id.$model->kabupaten}),
    'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Kota Asal','required' => true,'style'=>'width:500px','maxlength' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]);
?>
```

### EDIT:

You want the `kodepos` and `kabupaten` in one drop-down rather than making 2 drop-downs so change the code to the following

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'origin')->label('Origin')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(MKota::find()->all(),function($model){return $model->kodepos.$model->kabupaten}),function($model){return $model->kodepos.$model->kabupaten}),
    'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Kode Pos','required' => true,'style'=>'width:500px','maxlength' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: the dropdown is correct. thank you. but only kodepos attributes are included in the database. i want the kabupaten attribute to enter also in the database

Comment: are you saying that you want to save the `kodepos` and `kabupaten` for the field name `origin` in the database? @Herdi

Comment: well, change the `$from` parameter to use `closure` in the same way as i did for the `$to` and return your desired fields from the `closure`. @Herdi

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: i am talking about the `ArrayHelper::map($array,$from,$to)` parameter `$from` , you need to change it just like the `$to` parameter to use an anonymous function @Herdi

Comment: i have updated the code in the **EDIT** section see in the answer

Comment: it's work,  but I want to separate kodepos and kabupaten attributes in the database

Comment: thats, all i can do in this question , it wasnt mentioned in your question what you are asking, you should look into the documentation for yii2 on how to work on that